# How to crop and rotate an image to bounding box?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

- I have a dataset of thousands of images containing hands
- I also have .mat files which contain the coordinates of 4 corners of the bounding box
- However, the edges of these bounding boxes are at an angle with the x & y axis. For example,
  [image]
- I want to crop out the hands using the bounding box coordinates & then rotate the hands such that they are aligned with the x or y axis.

EDIT:

The hand is represented as follows:

However, please keep in mind that the rectangle is NOT straight. So, I'll have to rotate it to straighten it out.

[image]

Comment: can you show an example of how each rectangle is represented?

Comment: Do you have the image processing toolbox?

Comment: @m_power, Yes. I have image processing toolbox.

Answer (score 6):

Good one!

#### First step:

Compute the size of the rectangle

```
 width = sqrt( sum( (b-a).^2 ) );
 height = sqrt( sum( (c-b).^2 ) );
```

#### Second step:

Compute an affine transformation from `a`...`d` to an upright image

```
 Xin = [a(2) b(2) c(2) d(2)];
 Yin = [a(1) b(1) c(1) d(1)];
 Xout = [width 1 1 width];
 Yout = [1 1 height height];
 A = [Xin;Yin;ones(1,4)]';
 B = [Xout; Yout]';
 H = B \ A; % affine transformation
```

Note that despite the fact that we allow fo `H` to be affine, the choise of corners (depending on `width` and `height`) will acertain that `H` will not distort the cropped rectangle.

optionally use [`cp2tform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/cp2tform.html):

```
 H2 = cp2tform( [Xin;Yin]', [Xout;Yout]', 'nonreflectivesimilarity' );
```

#### Third step

Use the transformation to get the relevant image part

```
 thumb = tformarray( img, maketform( 'affine', H' ), ... %//'
                     makeresampler( 'cubic', 'fill' ), ...
                     1:2, 1:2, ceil( [height width] ), [], 0 );
```

optionally use [`imtransform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtransform.html):

```
 thumb = imtransform( img, H2, 'bicubic' );
```

---

#### A note regarding vectorization:

depends on how the coordinates of the corners are stored (`a`...`d`) the first two steps can be easily vectorize.

Comment: Are you sure that affine transformation is a good option? Affine transformation does NOT necessarily preserve angles or lengths. I would like the angles & lengths to be preserved.

Comment: @PrernaChikersal this is why we have the first step - making sure aspect ratio is preserved.

Comment: preserving the aspect ration is one thing, however the lengths will vary right? What are the pros/cons of using ur method compared to the other answer?

Comment: @PrernaChikersal you tell me. have you managed to implement the other solution?

Comment: Well, I am trying to decide on which one to use. My only concern with affine transformation is that it will not preserve the length, etc

Comment: use the optional method using `cp2tform` with `'nonreflectingsimilarity'` to ensure no distortions are made.

Comment: @PrernaChikersal is this solution working for you? do you still have problems? if this solution is working for you, please consider "accepting" it by clicking the "V" icon beside it.

Comment: I moved away from this problem (I don't need to use it anymore). I haven't tried this out yet. So, it still remains an open question.

Comment: I try to run it because i have the same problem and all the values inside of thumb are zeros,and of course when i do imshow i don't see the relevant rectangle i chose.

Comment: @Maayan which method are you using?

Comment: Without cp2tform and imtransform. The first options.

Comment: @Maayan please try the other method as well. Moreover does the resulting `H` matrix makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate images using the `imrotate` command.

You can crop images (once they are rotated properly) by using indexing.  i.e.

```
subimg = img( c(1):b(1), c(2):d(2) )
```

(note, the above line is assuming, you've tracked the corners through the `imrotate` command, so that c(2) == b(2), c(1) == d(1) etc.)

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "indexing". The coordinates of the bounding box I have are of the image before rotation. So, how can I use indexing to crop the image?

Comment: How do I track the corners using imrotate?

Comment: Hmm... @John, the angle of imrotate and the rotation matrix are same or opposite?

Comment: should the angle of rotation be the angle between the line joining a & b and the x-axis?

Comment: Personally I just do trial and error to answer those questions.