# How do i rotate my image and save data into a matrix?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, rotation

I have an intensity image where i marked with the impoly function a region of interest. I have a code that gives me back the vertices of the smallest rectangle still containing my polygon.
The rectangle is most of the times not aligned with the axes. I would like to receive the data inside the rectangle into a matrix form.I have been trying to find out the angle between the largest side of the rectangle and the x axis and then to rotate the image so the rectangle will be aligned with the axes.I will really appreciate any help or new ideas on how to extract the values inside my rectangle into a matrix.
Here is part of my code:

```
filename = uigetfile; %get the file name
obj = VideoReader(filename);
nFrames=obj.NumberOfFrames;
thisfig = figure();

 for k = 1 : nFrames  
this_frame = read(obj, k);
thisax = axes('Parent', thisfig);
image(this_frame, 'Parent', thisax);
if k==nFrames
title(thisax, sprintf('Frame #%d', k));
end

if k==1
    result=input('How many polygons would you like to draw? ');
    for i=1:result
    handle=impoly;
    accepted_pos = wait(handle);
    BW = createMask(handle); 
    sparse_image=sparse(BW);
    [XX, YY] = find(sparse_image);
    [rectx,recty]=minboundrect(XX,YY); %the function that returns the vertices of the rectangle

  points=[rectx(1),rectx(2),rectx(3),rectx(4);recty(1),recty(2),recty(3),recty(4)]
  distance1=((points(1,2)-points(1,1))^2+(points(2,2)-points(2,1))^2)^0.5;
  distance2=((points(1,3)-points(1,2))^2+(points(2,3)-points(2,2))^2)^0.5;

   if(distance1>distance2) %which side of the rectangle is the largest
      vector=[points(1,2)-points(1,1),points(2,2)-points(2,1)];
   else
      vector=[points(1,3)-points(1,2),points(2,3)-points(2,2)];
   end
   angleInDegrees = atan2(vector(2), vector(1)) * 180 / pi; %supposed angle between the largest side and the x axis

    end
end
```

To be clear: I get a video and split it into frames and i need to follow a certain area in all of the frames in the video. I'm dealing with a video but i split it into frames so i'm really dealing with images. The rectangle i get is slanted most of the times,i.e not aligned with the axes of my image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to crop and rotate an image to bounding box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045809/how-to-crop-and-rotate-an-image-to-bounding-box)

Comment: Yes! I have the same problem! I'm trying to understand what you wrote to see if it works for me but i couldn't understand how do you calculate the width and height of the slanted rectangle?

Comment: look at the drawing in the question to see how `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are defined. Then it's simply Euclidean distace computation. Run it in debug and see what it does.

Comment: BTW if you have comments regarding my answer to the other question - please post them there.

Answer (score 0):

Confusing question.
The code refers to videos, not images. 
Is the question about rotating an image? Is the question about retrieving a sub-matrix from an image?
Is the posted code really relevant to the question?
What have you tried?

From the doc:

```
this_frame = read(obj, k);
```

**video = read(obj)** reads in all video frames from the file associated with obj. The read method returns a H-by-W-by-B-by-F matrix, video, where H is the image frame height, W is the image frame width, B is the number of bands in the image (for example, 3 for RGB), and F is the number of frames read.

It seems that you do have the coordinates:

```
[rectx,recty]=minboundrect(XX,YY);
```

So I'd say that the matrix you're looking for is

```
A = this_frame(rectx(1):rectx(2), recty(1):rectx(y), 1, 1); % Red band
```

Please edit your question for clarity.